# Unable to ping A record on Route 53 from Windows EC2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have 2 A records setup in Route 53. Using fake details for obvious reasons.

```
ad.company.dev.local - a.a.a.a
dc1.company.dev.local - a.a.a.a
dc2.company.dev.local - b.b.b.b
```

From my Windows EC2 instance, I can ping ad.company.dev.local. But when I try for the other 2 I get the error

`Ping request could not find host dc1.company.dev.local. Please check the name and try again.`

I have tried *ipconfig /flushdns* but still the same error. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Was Route 53 configured as a "private hosted zone" specific to that VPC? Were all three A-Records configured the same way?

Comment: @john-rotenstein Yes it's a "private hosted zone" specific to that VPC. By "same way" if you mean settings they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

FYI. When running AWS Managed Directory, you need to use a conditional forwarder pointing to the VPC+2 IP address.

1. RDP into the Windows EC2 instance
2. If required, install the DNS Manager console
3. Connect to one of the AD servers using the DNS Manager console
4. Add a conditional forwarder pointing to the VPC+2 IP address
5. Add the required DNS entries into Route 53 for the DC hosted zone